# SQLAlchemy Attribute Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert some dummy values to a `db` table using `sqlalchemy`. But I am getting `'AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'` error,

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Float, create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
engine= create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
s = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine

s.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person')
s.execute(
'CREATE TABLE person (id INTEGER NOT NULL, '
'             name VARCHAR(255),'
'             PRIMARY KEY (id))')
s.commit()
for i in range(10):
    row = ('name-{}'.format(i),)
    s.execute("INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES (?)",(row))
s.commit()
```

When trying to run the above code, I get the following `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ashesh\DataWarehouse\Projects\Project-1\project1.py", line 30, in <module>
    s.execute("INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES (?)",(row))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1176, in execute
bind, close_with_result=True).execute(clause, params or {})
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 948, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1028, in _execute_clauseelement
keys = list(distilled_params[0].keys())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax instead:

```
for i in range(10):
    row = 'name-{}'.format(i)
    s.execute("INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES (:name)", {'name':row})
```

Comment: if you have same column repeated in sql like where id > 1 AND id < 10 or any other repeated column the dictionary will not accept repeated property